# VS Code refactoring in JS doesn't seem to work in unopened files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, refactoring, automated-refactoring

When trying to refactor function names, variable names, or class names within all files using F2 (as shown at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol), I only seem to have success when those other files are open in the editor. If they're closed, VS Code won't rename those instances. Am I missing something?

Before rename with files closed:
[image]

After rename with files closed:
[image]

Before rename with files open:
[image]

After rename with files open:
[image]

I tried looking into settings for refactor or replace, but didn't find anything that wasn't enabled that obviously should be. If I successfully rename something when a file is open, undo it, then close the file and re-attempt the refactor, it fails again.

EDIT: I submitted this as a bug to the vscode team on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andrii Dieiev on Github.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146120#issuecomment-1079793615

Adding a basic jsconfig.json file is enough to ensure all files in our project are interpreted as part of the workspace:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```